# How can I use sed/grep/awk to print the TLD's from a list of hostnames that have the TLD in different fields?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I have a very large list of hostnames from which I am trying to print the TLD (.com, .net, .info, etc.) of each host.  The problem is that the hosts have their TLDs in different fields, so I can't tell cut or awk to statically print one field.

Some example hostnames:

```
examplehost.net                             # tld is 2nd field (period delimited)
subdomain.otherhost.com                      # tld is 3rd field
subdomain.othersubdomain.yetanotherhost.info   # tld is 4th field
```

As a little workaround, I've just been adding a space to the end of each host that way I can include it in my regex pattern and grep for it.

```
sed 's/$/ /g' listofhosts.txt | grep -Eo '\.[a-z]{1,10} '
```

I was curious if there is a more elegant way to accomplish this.

Comment: `sed 's/ .*//; s/.*\.//'`

Comment: `awk -F. '{print $NF}' listofhosts.txt` maybe?

Comment: If any of the current answers solved your problem, please indicate so using the checkmark. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If your listofhosts.txt file does *not* have comments at the end of it, then steeldriver's commented command is how I would do it. Tell awk to split the fields on periods, then print the value of the last field:

```
awk -F. '{print $NF}' listofhosts.txt
```

Resulting in:

```
net
com
info
```

Answer (score 0):

With single ***grep*** (if *PCRE* supported):

```
grep -Po '.*\.\K[^.]+$' listofhosts.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -oE '\.[^.]+$'

perl -lne 'print /(\.[^.\s]+)\s/'

sed 's/^[[:space:]]*[^[:space:]]\{1,\}\([.][^.[:space:]]\{1,\}\)[[:space:]]\{1,\}.*/\1/'
```